# Worst case space complexity of pre-order binary tree traversal using iterative and recursive implementation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, stack, space-complexity

Considering the space complexity in the worst case of a completely skewed tree (essentially a linked list) using the iterative and recursive implementation below:

```
# Iterative
def preorderTraversal(self, root):
    if root is None:
        return []

    stack = [root]

    while stack:
        root = stack.pop()

        print root.val

        if root.right:
            stack.append(root.right)
        if root.left:
            stack.append(root.left)

# recursive
def preorderTraversal(self, root):
    if not root:
        return

    print(root.val)
    preorderTraversal(root.left)
    preorderTraversal(root.right)
```

- Iterative - in each iteration, exactly one node is popped out and one node pushed in, so stack has only one node throughout the loop. This is O(1)
- Recursion - since it needs to maintain call stack which contains all nodes when the code reaches the leaf node. This is O(n)

Questions:

1. Is my above understanding correct?
2. If so, why do we have a difference in space between the iterative and recursive implementations for the worst case? They are both stack-based, so intuitively I'd think they have the same time & space complexity in all cases. What's really causing this difference?
3. Is there a way to implement the iterative solution that matches exactly the recursive version in terms of space complexity in all cases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The indentation within `preorderTraversal()` is partly wrong.

Comment: @Armali Thanks for pointing that out. It was a copy-paste error and is corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my understanding above correct?

Considering the case where only `left` (or `right`, if we disregard tail optimization) nodes are populated, your understanding is correct, but such *a completely skewed tree* is not the worst case for the iterative implementation. There, with a tree like

```
    0
    ^
   1 8
   ^
  2 7
  ^
 3 6
 ^ 
4 5
```

the `stack` grows up to about *n/2*.

Comment: Actually, the example should screwed to the right side, right? given that the iterative pre-order traversal pushes the right sub-node into stack first.

Comment: No, just because it _pushes the right sub-node into stack first_, the secondly pushed left node is popped immediately thereafter in the next iteration, and the right node remains on the stack. The traversal order is denoted by the numbers in the example; the maximum stack after visiting node 3 is 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. Even both of the versions use a stack, they use it differently. You can't compare *the stack the data structure* and *the stack of calls*. The stack of calls is not popping the element until you come back from recursion, however, in the iterative version, the stack is popping each element when it visits it, it doesn't come back.